# Decent code visible example of Entity Framework, POCO and a tiered architecture in the wild?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

Can anyone point to a good example of an Entity Framework 4 based tiered architecture using POCOs in C#, preferably written from the aspect of introduction to the concept?

What I am looking for is something that shows off using POCOs in a higher tier, passing those back down the tiers to Entity Framework and into the database, with transforms going on as required.

I have seen a lot of articles based around one or the other, but nothing really that puts it all together in a "this is how it all works" example.

Cheers
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isnt the most loved example out there, but it has some good points. The implementation has some weak points, but its improved over time and doc accompying it is worth a read.

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "N-tier architecture" is being downplayed by the "Repository, Unit-of-Work, and Specification pattern" in a lot of articles. Using Repository, Unit-of-Work, and Specification means having an N-tier architecture. You can find lots of articles about this online. Here are some:

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-1-model-and-poco-classes/

http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/

http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/

http://www.hightech.ir/Tags/EntityFramework